# Lexus won't start

Tags: ignition, lexus

2005 Lexus LS430 will not turn over.  There is no clicking sound, which I think is the starter.  All lights work; dash and headlights.  When I Turn the key to the on position there is nothing.

Comment: Your post is a little confusing. You say "all lights work", but also, "when I turn key to on, there is nothing." Are you seeing lights when the ignition is on, is it just the "start" position that doesn't turn over the engine?

Comment: Welcome to the site ... yes, your question is a little confusing, and really doesn't have much detail in it. As it stands, it could be the starter, but could be in the ignition switch as well. Not much to go on here.

Answer (score 1):

Do lights dim when turning key to crank and brighten when released?

Could be a broken starter wire or anti-theft deterant system not allowing you to crank. Have seen low battery result in a no crank but its usually a slow crank or clicking.

Comment: Please try not to ask clarifying questions in your answer. That is what comments are for.

Comment: Thanks. I couldnt comment because it said I didnt have enough points so the only option was to answer.